# Can I install, and which version Ubuntu on an apple computer?

Tags: mac, versions, apple

This is the version of MacOS I have:

[image: MacOS version]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) It's worth running an Ubuntu USB live session to test an Intel Mac.